# Is there an ALT+Select equivalent for gedit or general text editors on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, text-editors

I'm primarily a Windows user, with experience using tools like Notepad++, Visual Studio, etc.

One handy feature is "block select", whereby I can use the ALT key to select a rectangular region of text.

When I try this on my linux box, it turns the cursor into a hand and moves the window around.

Is there a way to get the equivalent behavior out of gedit, eclipse, GPS (Gnat Programming Studio)?

Comment: This is similar to a previous question on selecting columns in various text editors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-select-columns-in-editors-atom-notepad-kate-vim-sublime-textpad-et BTW, Kate is an excellent text editor for Linux, similar to Notepad++, that allows column selection.

Comment: So the short story is that it's not possible in gedit and GPS. I can switch text editors with some amount of difficulty (due to the configuration of the dev VM), but I'm stuck with GPS for the near future.

Comment: http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/editing.html#using-an-external-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to toggle 
"Column selection mode".

(On Linux, plain Alt- keys are usually captured by the desktop manager and aren't usable by applications).

Answer (score 0):

In **CudaText** you can select column-blocks with Alt+drag - but first disable Alt+drag as move window operation in Linux settings. If you don't disable it, use Alt+Shift+arrows in CudaText.